Execution of aws-cli is insanely slow on MacOS
I am a linux user switching to Mac for work. The first problem I've encountered is with aws-cli, the mere execution of which takes about 4 seconds:
time aws --version

returns
aws-cli/2.17.2 Python/3.11.8 Darwin/23.4.0 exe/x86_64
aws --version  0.52s user 0.70s system 31% cpu 3.875 total

I'm running a fresh macOS Sonoma 14.4 on MacBook Air M2 16GB. I've installed aws-cli using GUI installer from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html Installation "for the current user" failed, so I installed it "for all users".
After linux, on which it was instantaneous, 4 seconds feels like a torture.
Any help will be appreciated!

Is this only for the first API call? I also noticed longer wait times for the initial API call, but subsequent ones seem to be done in < 1s. Were you using the same version of the AWS CLI on Linux?

Unfortunately not. It's every call.

The problem is that the official awscli installer contains only the Intel build and as you stated, you're on Aarch64 (Apple Silicon).
aws --version
aws-cli/2.17.2 Python/3.11.8 Darwin/23.5.0 exe/x86_64

The x86_64 states this build is for Intel - so it runs on Apple's Rosetta 2 translation layer, which is a huge performance burden.
Solution
Please install awscli with HomeBrew.
As you mentioned, you switched from Linux, so it is the perfect time to meet HomeBrew - you will use this package manager very often to install stuff onto your new Mac :)
First install brew onto your machine following the instructions.
Then install awscli:
brew install awscli

After a while, you can verify awscli is a native arm64 build, indeed:
time aws --version
aws-cli/2.17.1 Python/3.11.9 Darwin/23.5.0 source/arm64
aws --version  0.22s user 0.05s system 98% cpu 0.281 total

Much better :)

Many thanks! That definitely helped. However I am not getting anything close to your 0.28. Typically I get ~1.5 seconds, which is way better than 4 sec!!! But still feels slow:
aws --version  0.30s user 0.29s system 40% cpu 1.465 total

Hi Alex! To be honest, 1.5s is still far from something we could accept. I suggest to start investigating if this lag happens with other Python-based apps, or is it related to an antivirus software (like ESET Cybersecurity), etc. It is a pity you experience such things with your new Mac, I hope you can solve it and have a lot of productive hours on macOS.
